# TooManyTabs on Chrome - losing all the stored tabs - how to recover?

Tags: google-chrome, data-recovery, google-chrome-extensions, browser-tabs

In the past two weeks I have been starting to use the TooManyTabs extension on Chrome and have put a few hundred tabs into TMT. However, today, I have discovered that all the tabs I have put in the TMT have disappeared and I have not previously interacted with TMT. My browser did not sync with google account so it probably would not be retrievable from the cloud.

How to recover those tabs being put in TMT?

Answer (score 0):

The lastest version of TMT offers backup to Google Drive. So if you have logged in to TMT, you can restore your tabs.

You can also use `Ctrl + Alt + T` to restore previous sessions. 
Doing this multiple times will restore all your tabs

I think you should consider using The Great Suspender instead of TMT

Comment: 1.I haven't logged in to TMT either 2. Restoring previous sessions would probably not work as I was gradually opening and closing tabs throughout my browsing 3. suspended tabs using great suspender would still appear on the top bar, and thousands of tab on top of there isn't exactly navigatable

Comment: @user930067 Then use Ctrl + Alt + T

Comment: updated comment above in respond to ctrl + alt + T

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm out of ideas, as TMT officially says that they do not offer any type of recovert

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found for this problem was switching to using a combination of The Great Suspender and Tabs Outliner.

Tabs Outliner will keep a record of every tab you've ever opened in a hierarchical tree (which is extremely useful) unless you specifically delete tabs from the tree. You can close tabs to free up more memory and prevent a crash, while still retaining a clickable link on the tree; or you can trash it and remove for good.

The best feature I think is the fact that it is constantly saving your tab trees so that if you open too many and crash, you can open it up and go right back to the tree and not lose a beat, start opening up full windows of tabs or just individuals and try to slow down for once!

{easier said than done; believe me, I know....}

Comment: As mentioned above, The Great Suspender does not match my use case. I have used tab outliner some years ago but still not quite work. And this still does not solve the problem of how to restore my already lost tabs.